Clarification on Borsuk-Ulam theorem
Let $f: \mathbb{S}^2\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be a continuous odd function. Does there exists a connected component, $\Gamma$, of $K=f^{-1}(0)$ which is invariant under the antipodal map $P(x)=-x$, $x\in \mathbb{S}^2$? (i.e. $P(\Gamma)=\Gamma$).
This question seems to be already answered in this post, but I am confused about the two answers which seem to be contradicting each other. The first answer, which is accepted by OP, provides an example where "no two antipodal points in $K$ can be joined by a continuous path ranging in $K$", where $K=f^{-1}(0)$. The second answer proves that "the antipodal map on $\mathbb{S}^2$ sends some component of $Z$ to itself," where $Z=f^{-1}(0)$.
How do we reconcile these two results?

Do you understand the difference between "connected" and "path-connected?"

Yes, I did not realize those two different assumptions for the two answers. Thank you.

The $K$ constructed in the first (accepted) answer is not path-connected, but it is connected. The second answer proves that it must be connected.
The OP started by asking about path-connectedness, accepted the answer, and then edited their question to ask about connectedness, saying:

If so, then the Borsuk-Ulam proof via this approach can still be salvaged


Thank you, fish.
